# Limitations on Excel "Linked Picture"

Tags: microsoft-excel

I must be running into a limitation or possibly a bug on the "Linked Picture" functionality in Excel.  I have a small section (B4:K14) I would like to create as a linked picture, but for some reason the "Linked Picture" option in the Paste menu disappears when I include cell K14.  I can do a link on B4:J14 and a link on B4:K13, both which exclude the cell and they both work.  Interestingly I can also do a Linked Picture for B14:K14 and K4:K14, both of which include that cell.  My current workaround is to do two linked images and then group them together.  Any ideas what limitation I may be running into?

Excel 2013 (15.0.515.1000) 64-bit

Comment: Did this problem appear in all Excel Workbooks or specific Workbook?

Comment: Specific Workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact answer, but it seems to have something to do with the table formatting.  I made a copy of the cells and can copy both the formula and the styles onto the same sheet, another sheet, or another workbook and everything works.  As soon as I do a full copy or set a table format, the "Linked Picture" option goes away.